# Adding headers and cookies in Web Socket open connection request in Python

Tags: python, websocket

To authenticate myself I need to add an authentication cookie and some header fields and value while I am opening a connection with web socket server. I have explored a lot but could not find any simple clear cut Python library that helps me do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Requests** library: docs.python-requests.org

- [Custom headers](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers).
- [Cookies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies).

Comment: That library is to establish a REST call I think, I want to perform websocket handshake

Answer (score 0):

[AutobahnPython](https://autobahn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) supports both inspecting and setting HTTP headers during the WebSocket opening handshake. See [here](https://autobahn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/websocket/programming.html#opening-handshake) and [here](https://autobahn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/autobahn.websocket.html#autobahn.websocket.interfaces.IWebSocketChannel.onConnect).

Comment: Did the links change? I don't see the "here" links pointing to the exact documentation for dealing with handshake, headers, cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If it fits your needs, you could check out the `urllib` and `urllib2` libraries. They're higher level libraries, that let you do this kind of stuff fairly easily. For example, sending a request with certain header fields would look like this:

```
import urllib2
import urllib

#POST data you might want to send. If you don't want to send post data, just set this as None or blank, e.g. data = {}
data = urllib.urlencode({"username":uname, "passwd":yourpass, "submit":"Submit"})
#add as many header fields as you like
headers = {"Cookie":"<<your cookies go here>>", "Referer":"blahblah"} 

request = urllib2.Request("yourwebserver.com", data, headers)
#here you get your response back
response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Hope this is some help to you! Cheers!:)